# Rails 5: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently developing my new web application, therefore I want to implement an invitation system for registered users. I followed a tutorial I found on the web, but I ran into some trouble.

I'm trying to display the "Invite Form" on the profile page.

So this is my registartions/edit.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for(@invite, url: invites_path) do |f| %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
     <%= f.label :email %>
     <%= f.email_field :email %>
     <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
    <% end %>
```

Here I get the error **First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty** for `@invite`, I already tried `Invite.new` and `:invite` and both work fine.

This is my invites_controller

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
  @invite = Invite.new(invite_params) # Make a new Invite
  @invite.sender_id = current_user.id # set the sender to the current user
  if @invite.save
     InviteMailer.new_user_invite(@invite, new_user_registration_path(invite_token: @invite.token)).deliver #send the invite data to our mailer to deliver the email
  else
     # oh no, creating an new invitation failed
  end
end

def show
end

def index
end

def update
end

def edit
end

def invite_params
  params.require(:invite).permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id, :email, :token)
end

end
```

My User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invitations, class_name: 'Invite', foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
  has_many :sent_invites, class_name: 'Invite', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
end
```

My Invite Model

```
class Invite < ApplicationRecord      
belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the object in `new` and `edit` actions:

```
def new
  @invite = Invite.new
end

def edit
  @invite = Invite.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @klasarn missed your note on 'display the ... on the profile page', `@invite` should be set in whatever action form is rendered in